# hide div (it contains only script tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I want to hide some divs on my webpage, they contain only script tags...how do I do that?

for example..

```
<div>
   <div>
       <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">some js code</script>
       </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">some js code</script>
   </div> 
</div>
```

basically these divs are empty but they have script tags in it so using empty is not working. Can anyone please suggest how can I remove these divs. My aim is to remove the parent tag itself if there is no value in any of the child.

how can I identify that all the childs are empty for given parent. (I want to check for empty childs and even if it has script I want to ignore that and consider it as empty and finally if all the childs are empty, I want to remove the parent node)

for example consider this...(there can be any number of child, if all are empty then remove the parent)(I want to ignore the script tag and consider that as empty if no value is there other then script tag)

```
 <div class="printpage">
<div class="flip">
    <div>empty div</div>
    <div>
        <div>
        <div>empty div</div>
            <div>
            <div>empty div</div>
                <div>
                    <script>script</script>
                    <div>empty div</div>
                </div>
            <script>script</script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flip">
    <div>empty div</div>
    <div>
        <div>
        <div>empty div</div>
            <div>
            <div>empty div</div>
                <div>
                    <script>script</script>
                    <div>empty div</div>
                </div>
            <script>script</script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could give them a class if you know that they're going to be empty (for example `<div class="removeAfterLoad">...</div>`) and then use `$(".removeAfterLoad").remove()`.

Comment: Your divs do not only contain script tags, they also contain white-space text nodes.

Comment: what do you actually want, for these whitespace-only divs to be _invisible_ so they don't cause line breaks, padding, etc, or actually removed from the DOM?

Comment: why cant you include these script tags into u'r head section and delete this div's from u'r html.

Comment: @ssilas777 Why can't you write in English instead of txtspk?

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for pointing out that horrible mistake

Comment: @Alnitak I want to remove the parent node from the dom, if all the childs are empty (or even if they have script tag and if they are empty I want to remove them from dom)

Comment: Is your question "How do I remove them?" or "How do I identify/select them?" (Even ignoring whitespace) the script tags themselves aren't empty since they have code in them. Are you saying you want to remove elements that don't have any visible non-whitespace content, including either direct content or content of descendant elements?

Comment: @nnnnnn - yes  I want to remove div elements that don't have any visible non-whitespace content

Comment: @Kalish so the `<script>` stuff is really a red herring - you just want to completely **remove** any DIV that does not contain visible markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** this was harder than it sounds.  This is an updated answer following @VisioN's observation that the script element's own text wasn't being ignored.

This should check whether any element apart from the `<script>` element contains any text output.

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $c = $this.contents();
    for (var i = 0, n = $c.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var c = $c.get(i);
        var tag = c.tagName;
        if (tag === 'SCRIPT') continue;                 // ignore script tag
        if (tag === 'IMG' || tag === 'CANVAS') return;  // non-text output
        if ($.trim($(c).text()).length > 0) {           // check text content
            return;
        }
    }
    $this.hide();
});​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/PdCnL/

Comment: I'm not sure if it works. `$(this).text()` will return the content of `<script>` tags.

Comment: @VisioN crap, so it does...  I misread the question as using external scripts, not inline.

Comment: Yes, seems to work fine. However, I still doubt about the author's note: *My aim is to remove the parent tag itself if there is no value in any of the child*. Truly uncertain.

Comment: @VisioN ah, he added that afterwards.  Dammit.

Comment: @all, I have updated the question, if there are n number of child of a parent, child can have n number of sub child or script tag, but if they all are empty then I want to remove the parent tag. Please help!

Comment: @Kalish I suspect that my answer should now give you enough to work with.

Comment: yes, it does, it helps a lot, I will carry on from here! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can use `:has` selector:</strike>

```
$('div:has(script)').hide();
```

Or:

```
$('div > script').parent().hide()
```

---

```
$('div > script').parent().filter(function() {
    return !$('script', this).siblings().length
}).remove()
```

Comment: Wouldn't this remove/hide the blocks if they also contained other stuff?

Comment: will that guarantee that the div is empty and has only script tag in it?  (I want to hide/remove only the divs which are empty and has script tag)

Comment: @Kalish It hides the div element if it has a script _child_ element.

Comment: but I have other divs which are not empty but has script child, so (I want to hide/remove only the divs which are empty or  it has only script tag)

Comment: @Kalish Okay, try the updated code. It hides the div that have only script child element.

Comment: @undefined your code is ignoring any text nodes that are adjacent to those elements.

Comment: @Alnitak You are correct, I assumed that script tags have no adjacent text nodes, in that case your code does the trick, well done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery filter` . following code will make sure that only those div get hidden which contain script tag only.

```
var divs = $("div")​.filter(function(){
    console.log();
 return $(this).text().replace(/\s/gi,'') == $('script', this).text().replace(/\s/gi,'');    

}).hide();
alert(divs.length); // return 3
```

​

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mH4Tp/)