# Hide div if it only contains <script> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Similar to this 6-year old question, but I'm not looking at parent elements and wondering if there is a better solution? [hide div (it contains only script tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582331/hide-div-it-contains-only-script-tag/12582362#12582362)

Question:
My website has some blocks for google adsense advertisements. These blocks are just styled divs (background color, padding, margin, border-radius etc.) There is nothing in them except for the adsense script tags (and of course white space/text nodes, etc.). When a user has an ad block extension/plug-in, these divs still display, but they appear totally empty on the screen, which is not desirable. Therefore, I'm looking for a way to hide these divs if no ad is rendered. Using `:empty` or does not work since it still picks up the `<script>` tags.

Div element:

```
<div class="contentBlock"><script>//adsense code</script></div>
```

Perhaps there is a better way of tackling or conceptualizing this problem? If so, I'm open to alternative solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason the script tags have to go in the div?

Comment: @Deadron - That's how ad scripts usually work. They do their thing with `document.write`, so the ad appears where the page author wants it to appear.

Comment: Is the class for every `ad` content always `contentBlock` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `script` tags, and then check to see if the blocks are empty. In code that runs **after** the ad code would run if it were allowed to:

```
var blocks = $(".contentBlock");
blocks.find("script").remove();
blocks.each(function() {
    var div = $(this);
    if (!div.html().trim()) {
        div.remove();
    }
});
```

Or if you like chaining a lot:

```
$(".contentBlock")
    .find("script")
    .remove()
    .end()
    .each(function() {
        var div = $(this);
        if (!div.html().trim()) {
            div.remove();
        }
    });
```

If you have to support obsolete browsers, use `$.trim()` instead of the native `String.prototype.trim` (or polyfill it).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need a feature which is on CSS4 proposed list: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#has-pseudo

> The relational pseudo-class, :has(), is a functional pseudo-class
>   taking a relative selector list as an argument. It represents an
>   element if any of the relative selectors, when absolutized and
>   evaluated with the element as the :scope elements, would match at
>   least one element.
>   ...
>
> The following selector matches  elements that don’t contain any heading elements:
>
> section:not(:has(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6))

Another workaround is to use jquery to mark divs with content and then remove/hide the others. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mczv6gys/

```
$('div.contentBlock').has('p, span, img, div').addClass('markerClass'); // P or any other typical tag
$('div.contentBlock').not('.markerClass').addClass('hideClass'); // eg display:none
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have the ability to either hide the div, or replace it with new content if AdSense hides the content.**

If this example isn't working, your going to want to deal with the content dynamically created from Adsense. Such as a check for `$("#google_ads_frame1").css('display')=="none")`. Instead of checking your container div. Which would work, it was tested.

- You wrap your content into a container / div for strictly
  advertisements. Then set a timeout function to determined said
  issues. If adblock enabled, then show alternative content such as a
  video, poster, iframe, etc.
- Since adblock hides stuff with css too, you can then edit the css to
  ultimately hide everything if enabled instead of replacing. Two
  options.

> Change snippet timeout to whatever time you want to wait to check
>   after page loaded, to handle async ads.

```js
// Page has loaded
      window.onload = function(){ 
        // Set a timeout function for async google ads
        setTimeout(function() { 
          // We are targeting the first banner ad of AdSense
          var ad = document.querySelector(".ads");
          // If the ad contains no innerHTML, adblock is enabled
          // Or check adsense's generated content 
          // $("#google_ads_frame1").css('display')=="none")
          if (ad && ad.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, "").length == 0) {
            // Adblock hides with css also, or just hide everything.
            ad.style.cssText = 'display:block !important; background-color: LightCoral;'; 
            // Replace, if adblock enabled
            ad.innerHTML = 'We detected adblock';
          }
        }, 1); // Change this to 2000 to run after two seconds, to handle async ads
      };
```

```css
.ads {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<p><b>Example 1:</b> Let us simulate an adblock situation, the <code>script</code> tag did not load, hence adblock</p>

<div class="ads"></div>

<p><b>Example 2:</b> Let us simulate no adblock, <code>script</code> tag loaded</p>

<div class="ads"><script></script>Adblock ran</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you support ES6 features, you can filter `.contentBlock` which every nodes satisfy condition is "empty" textNode, is Script or is comment:

```js
let emptyBlocks = [...document.querySelectorAll('.contentBlock')].filter(block =>
  [...block.childNodes].every(node =>
    (node.nodeName === '#text') ?
       !node.textContent.trim(): 
       ['SCRIPT','#comment'].includes(node.nodeName)
  )
);



emptyBlocks.forEach(function(block){
  block.classList.add('empty');  
});
```

```css
.contentBlock{
  min-height:50px;
  width:200px;
  outline: solid 2px red;
  margin:2px;
}

.contentBlock.empty{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentBlock">
  <script>//nothing's happened</script><!--comment-->
</div>

<div class="contentBlock">
  <script>document.write('something\'s happened');</script>
</div>

<div class="contentBlock">
  <!--comment-->
  <script></script>
<!-- empty text nodes with spaces and tabulations -->

          


</div>

<div class="contentBlock">
<!--//-->
text node
</div>
```